# Paravirtualization on Windows

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

Is there any hypervisor that can be installed on Windows and supports [paravirtualized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paravirtualization) guests? For now I have Win7 on x86_64.

VMWare had a paravirtualization interface called VMI, but it was [retired](http://blogs.vmware.com/guestosguide/2009/09/vmi-retirement.html) in 2009.

Comment: Why do you need paravirtualization and what kind of paravirtualization? There's VMI, but there's also **paravirt-ops**.

Comment: because paravirtualization is faster. I need to spin up a linux VM and measure its performance.